# Storing methods in a lambda and sending to an object

Tags: ruby, jruby, ruby-1.9

Is is possible to call functions on (send messages to) an object if the functions are stored in a variable as a lambda?

Say I have an array like `%w(a b c)`

I can then chain methods like:

```
%w(a b c).reverse.map(&:upcase) # => ["C", "B", "A"]
```

Is it possible to extract the chained method calls to a variable and apply them to other array objects?

```
transform = -> { reverse.map(&:upcase) }
```

I've tried the following but have not had any luck:

**Using JRuby 1.7.1**

```
%w(a b c).send(transform)
TypeError: #<Proc:0x19a639d8@(irb):12 (lambda)> is not a string
```

And

```
%w(a b c).send(&transform)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

**Using Ruby 1.9.3**

```
%w(a b c).send(transform)
TypeError: #<Proc:0x007fa0721f0dc8@(irb):1 (lambda)> is not a symbol
```

And

```
%w(a b c).send(&transform)
ArgumentError: no method name given
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see at least two approaches:

1) You seem to like to write lambdas with an implicit receiver (I wouldn't recommend it, `self` obviously changes), you have [instance_exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) for that:

```
transform = -> { reverse.map(&:upcase) }
["a", "b", "c"].instance_exec(&transform)
#=> ["C", "B", "A"]
```

2) Write a custom extension, for example `Object#apply`:

```
class Object
  def apply(block, *args)
    block.call(self, *args)
  end
end

transform = -> strings { strings.reverse.map(&:upcase) }
["a", "b", "c"].apply(transform)
#=> ["C", "B", "A"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using `instance_eval` would self ever not be the receiving object?

Comment: instance_eval also sends the object as first argument to the block, so you'll get an error (since the lambda gets 0 arguments).

Comment: derp. I meant `instance_exec`, not `instance_eval`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but that's the purpose of instance_eval/instance_exec, executing a block with `self` set an object. The problem is obvious, you have a closure (still with access to local variables, but `self`, `@var` and so on, change its receiver).

Comment: 6 year old answer and just solved my problem I was blocked at for over 3 days

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def transform; reverse.map(&:upcase) end
end

%w(a b c).send(:transform)
```